# Can't install MS Bot Emulator 3.5.29. Error - this app can't run on your PC?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, appimage

I am trying to run the Microsoft Bot Emulator setup program:

```
botframework-emulator-Setup-3.5.29.exe
```

My system is a Windows 8.1 64-bit install with 16 GB of memory.  When I run the setup program I get the following error from Win81:

*This app can't run on your PC.
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher*

I tried downloading the AppImage file too and running that version on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box.  But then I get an error message saying *libfuse.so.2* can not be found, despite the *fuse* package *definitely* being installed on that PC.

UPDATE: Tried it on another Win8.1-64-bit station and a Win10 station.  Same error message.

How can I get this thing installed?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @JasonSowers No.  Are you having the same problem?

Comment: No sir, was wanting to help.  where are you downloading the emulator from?

Comment: @JasonSowers https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v3.5.29

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases

I downloaded the appropriate version of BotFramework-Emulator and run it. It worked. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

I also run BotFramework-Emulator in node js server locally. It ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your PC and run the bot emulator setup, it would work fine.